# Toon shader making jagged shadows

Tags: shaders, npr

I've tried to find an answer but so far no luck. All of the ones I could find went over my head. So I'm caving in and asking this question myself.

I'm very new to Blender and 3D stuff, so bear with me, but when I activate the toon shader, it gives me a weird jagged mess instead of a smooth curve. Must be something obvious I haven't noticed, but I can't figure it out. Here's what it looks like:

[image: ahhhhhhhh]

If anybody could enlighten me on what in the world is happening that would be appreciated.

Comment: Set your shading to smooth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your object is smooth shaded, as GiantCowFilms mentioned.

Select it and press *smooth* in *3D view > toolbar* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Tool > Shading*:

[image]