# How can I create simple toon colors in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, npr

I'm having trouble creating toon colors, without shadow. Just clear solid color.

I use 2.75 and 2.76

I get this  [image]
[image]

How can I create flat cartoon colors? 
[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles  , and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15004/toon-shader-making-jagged-shadows

Comment: Cycles wasn't made for this. While it can still be used this way, maybe you should use the Internal render for this.

Comment: @cegaton every example in this link generate shadows or only 2 not 3 or more color

Comment: @MarkoLustro can you edit your question an add  an example of the kind of image you are after?

Comment: I ask about complete flat color. For example I set red and blender show me 3 red shapes. Light, darkest and darked red. I create image but i dont know how produce it in blender.